# Styling Wordpress Dropdown Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I'm trying to style a dropdown menu from the following php code that I inserted into my blog page... http://www.patagoniariverguides.com

```
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'show_option_none'   => '',
'orderby'            => 'ID', 
'order'              => 'ASC',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1, 
'child_of'           => 0,
'exclude'            => '',
'echo'               => 1,
'selected'           => 0,
'hierarchical'       => 0, 
'name'               => 'cat',
'id'                 => '',
'class'              => 'postform',
'depth'              => 0,
'tab_index'          => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'hide_if_empty'      => false,
```

); ?>

The menu that is displayed on the page is your typical generic grey dropdown menu. I have been able to style it a little, but would like to fully customize the look.

- I would like to remove the border radius
- Would like to change the appearance of the actual dropdown items
- Would like to change the arrow button

Any ideas?

Comment: Use CSS! To solve your problems.

Comment: And what is the problem? You can style it any way you like it using css :)

Comment: Yes, I realize that I can style it using CSS, which I have done! I'm having issues with some of the classes and the CSS rules are not applying.

Comment: Hbirjand.... REALLY? Obviously you didn't read my post or visit the page. Thanks for a worthless comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a ready made navigation. So you need to use the developer tools in any browser to sniff out the reasons its not working. this will at least get you to see the navigation:

```
.ubermenu > ul > li:hover > .ubermenu-submenu-drop{
    z-index: 999;
    min-height: 294px !important;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible

}
```

You may need to assign !important tags depending how your stylesheets are arranged.

Comment: I'm reffering to the category menu below the slider, which is not Ubermenu. This is the menu spit out by wordpress code. Here is the CSS I have used so far, but some is not working... 

select#cat.postform {
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #2a8abb;
 font-family: 'Oswald'!important;
 text-transform: uppercase!important;
}

select#cat.postform > level-0{
 text-transform: uppercase!important;
 font-family: 'Oswald'!important;
}

Comment: What browser are you running? I'm using chrome, and I inspected the element of the drop down menu on on your blog page and I see all of those styles being applied. They're even appearing as the most pertinent styles

Comment: I'm in Chrome. On my end I still have a border radius of 5px and the sub-level items are not styled.